# How to retrieve Meteor.js Collection then pass it to a function after DOM loads

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

How can a query on the collection be executed first, then execute another function when a particular `div` has been rendered?

If I were to do the following, I get an error from `.highcharts()` stating that it is unable to find the div `#chart`.

**main.html**

```
<template name="chart">
    <div id="chart">{{init}}</div>
</template>
```

**main.js**

```
Template.chart.init = function() {
    // Get results of query first
    var data = myCollection.find();

    data.forEach(function(row) {
        console.log(data.price); // yes we received the collection
    });

    // Then pass to function
    $('#chart').highcharts(data);
};
```

Now If I were to call the function `highcharts()` after the template dom has been rendered via `Template.chart.rendered` as shown below, I get an error stating that the variable `data` is not found.

```
Template.chart.init = function() {
    var data = myCollection.find();

    data.forEach(function(row) {
        console.log(data.price);
    });
};


Template.chart.rendered = function() {
    $('#chart').highcharts(data)
}
```

Here it appears that `Template.chart.rendered` runs before `Template.chart.init`. How can I run the `highcharts` function after `data` has been retrieved from mongo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example doesn't work because Meteor calls your helper functions as it figures out what to render.  At that point your chart template doesn't yet exist in the DOM.

Your second example doesn't work because of a scope problem.  You're trying to use a variable in the rendered handler that only exists in init.

This should work:

```
Template.chart.rendered = function() {
  $('#chart').highcharts(myCollection.find());
};
```

---

If you need to do calculated values, there are a couple of ways to approach it.

**Approach #1: Change the collection on the client**

Pros: easy and fast to develop

Cons: client browser has to do the calculation, which - depending on the collection size and the calculation - could be slow

Example:

```
var dataWithCalculations = _.map(myCollection.find(), function(document) {
  document.someValue = document.someOtherValue * 2;
  return document;
});
$('#chart').highcharts(dataWithCalculations);
```

I'm not sure if this approach is reactive or not.  If it's not, it should be easy to fix by using a [dependency](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps).

**Approach #2: Use a transform**

Pros: easy and fast to develop

Cons: not reactive

Example:

```
Forms = new Meteor.Collection("forms", {
 transform: function(document) {
   document.someValue = document.someOtherValue * 2;
   return document;
 }
});
```

**Approach #3: Use a custom publication**

Pros: Reactive, calculation run on the server

Cons: Not easy or straightforward

Example: Check the count-by-rooms [example](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish) in the Meteor documentation

Comment: That makes sense! But I need to iterate through `myCollection` and perform a few more calculations first before passing the results to the function `highcharts()`. How would this be done?

Comment: In the second example, removing the `var` from `var data = ...` gave the same error of being undefined

Comment: I added some info about calculated values to my answer